# Edit photos online to paint out a certain section?

Tags: webapp-rec

I have a Flickr account. I have photos. I want to edit out a section of a photo on Flickr. I want to cover up or blacken out a part of a photo. A simple paint brush to paint a colour over an area is all I need.

However Flickr's integrated photo editor, Picnic, doesn't support this.

Is there any other online Flickr photo editor?

I don't want to have to download a photo and upload it to a new site (if I'm doing that, I can just use GIMP on my desktop).

Answer (score 1):

[Pixlr](http://www.pixlr.com/editor/) can open images from URIs and is very powerful.

Comment: A good start, however it can't import directly from Flickr, and most importantly, can't save the image back to flickr.